# JFrame causes Java to crash

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, crash, jframe

For some unknown reason creating a new JFrame is causing Java to crash. Not a class extending JFrame, just the javax.swing.JFrame class itself:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new JFrame("Test");
    });
```

On running this code I get the Windows (10) error message dialog

> Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.

Also opening Eclipse's WindowBuilder causes Eclipse to crash - Which I suspect may be related.

I have restarted my computer (the solution to 99% of IT problems) but unfortunately this seems to lie within that remaining 1%.

Comment: Update Java, eclipse and retry

Comment: I reinstalled both the Java JRE and JDK, as well as updating Eclipse from Neon to Oxygen. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Can you post the OS crash dump?

Comment: I figured that it was my graphics drivers. They were a version behind because the latest one doesn't play nicely with windows 10. Updating and rolling back again seems to have done the trick.
I feel bad now for making a post that wasn't really relevant, but I believed that Java was behaving weirdly when it wasn't.

Comment: My suspicion was that something needed updating. But I have been using OS X for a while so this did not even cross my mind. No worries